# laravel excel 3.1 import value not formula

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-5, phpexcel

Ok, so i trying to import xlsx file to my Database using Laravel 5.7 and Laravel Excel 3.1. Importing works but unfortunately I have file from another source and there are formulas in cells. My problem is, that I importing this file, and it works but instead values I see formulas it self:

> "=_xlfn.IFNA(VLOOKUP(F13,Data!C26:E92,3,0),"")"

and should be:

> Country

I have to see values not formulas. 
I've tried change calculated option to False or True, but nothing changed.

Could somebody help me with this?

**UsersImport.php** file:

```
namespace App\Imports;

use App\Form;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToArray;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMappedCells;

class UsersImport implements WithMappedCells, 
                                                        ToArray
{
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */

    use Importable;

    public function mapping(): array
    {
        return [
            'campaign_name' => 'F11',
            'country' => 'F12',
            'language' => 'F15',
            'region' => 'F17',
            'ms_region' => 'F19',
            'retailer_name' => 'F21',
            'start_date' => 'F23',
            'end_date' => 'F25',
            'quarter' => 'F27',
            'campaign_market' => 'F29',
            'campaign_execution_type' => 'F31',
            'reimbursement' => 'F33',
        ];
    }

    public function array(array $row)
    {
        return [ 
            'campaign_name' => $row['campaign_name'],
            'country' => $row['country'],
            'language' => $row['language'],
            'region' => $row['region'],
            'ms_region' => $row['ms_region'],
            'retailer_name' => $row['retailer_name'],
            'start_date' => $row['start_date'],
            'end_date' => $row['end_date'],
            'quarter' => $row['quarter'],
            'campaign_market' => $row['campaign_market'],
            'campaign_execution_type' => $row['campaign_execution_type'],
            'reimbursement' => $row['reimbursement'],
        ];
    }
}
```

**MyController** file:

```
public function import(Request $request)
{
    $data = [];
    $this->validate($request, array(
        'file'      => 'required'
    ));

    if($request->hasFile('file')){
        $extension = File::extension($request->file->getClientOriginalName());
        if ($extension == "xlsx" || $extension == "xls" || $extension == "csv" || $extension == "xlsm") {
            $name = $request->file->getClientOriginalName();

            $data = (new UsersImport)->toArray($name);
            dd($data);

            return redirect('/');
            } 
        }else {
            Session::flash('error', 'File is a '.$extension.' file.!! Please upload a valid xls/csv file..!!');
            return back();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

try
`use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithCalculatedFormulas;`
on `UsersImport.php`

Comment: No offence, but this is the perfect example of a non-answer, made all the more hilarious by the fact that the laravel excel documentation also has absolutely no instruction on HOW to use it. So for anyone stumbling upon this and wondering what "use" means:

add: "use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithCalculatedFormulas;"  in your Data Model.
Then implement it with the class, such as:
"class MyCustomImport implements WithCalculatedFormulas"

The model will then work by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone confused.

You need to use `WithCalculatedFormulas` in `use` sections and implement it in `class`:

**MyImportClass.php**

```
namespace App\Imports;

[...]
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithCalculatedFormulas;

class MyImportClass implements WithCalculatedFormulas
{
     [...]
}
```